# Exe self-modifies strings searched in debugger

Tags: windows, x86, pe, x64dbg

I'm studying a Windows binary file and while searching for some string I noticed the EXE modifies the searched string, e.g., if I search "This is a string", it's modified to "his is a string" (the modified string is then showed inside the app). I tried using ScyllaHide in x64Dbg but it didn't work. Detect It Easy shows only "(Heuristic)Protector: Generic[High entropy]".

Does anyone know which packer(s) do that? And how to approach that?